# Linearity of uncertainty

Tags: probability, information-theory

I've always used Shannon's entropy for measuring uncertainty, but I wonder why to use a logarithmic approach. Why shouldn't uncertainty be linear?

For instance, consider the following pairs of distributions:

$$ \left[0.9, 0.1\right], \left[0.99, 0.01\right] $$

$$ \left[0.4, 0.6\right], \left[0.49, 0.51\right] $$

Then you have the following uncertainty measures:
$$
H([0.9, 0.1]) = 0.46899559358928122\\
H([0.99, 0.01]) = 0.080793135895911181\\
H([0.4,0.6]) = 0.97095059445466858\\
H([0.49, 0.51]) = 0.9997114417528099
$$

With the following example I just want show that it doesn't satisfy linearity:

$$
H([0.9, 0.1]) - H([0.99, 0.01]) \simeq 0.3882
$$

$$
H([0.49, 0.51]) - H([0.4, 0.6]) \simeq 0.02876
$$

As we can see, distributions that are closer to $[1,0]$ or $[0,1]$ tend faster to zero.

May be this is more a philosophic question but I think that may be someone could give me alternative measures of uncertainty that may be linear or, at least, provide some explanation to the rationale of this approach.

Thanks!

**EDIT** I don't mean linearity in the whole space but in the intervals $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and $[\frac{1}{2}, 1]$. Since, as @r.e.s. comments, is a required property for such a measure that $f(0)<f(\frac{1}{2})$ and $f(1)<f(\frac{1}{2})$

Comment: Why do you expect $ H(X) =  -\sum_{i=1}^n {p(x_i) \log_b p(x_i)} $ to be linear?

Comment: I don't understand how the difference between the entropy of two different distributions measures uncertainty. Uncertainty of what? Is *uncertainty* a well-defined technical term in information theory that I am unaware of?

Comment: @draks: I know that $H(X)$ is not linear... I wonder if there is another approach to measure uncertainty that is actually linear.

Comment: @RahulNarain: No, the difference doesn't measure the uncertainty, it was just an example of the non-linearity. Yes, in information theory the uncertainty of a discrete random variable is defined as the entropy of its distribution. More info: [Entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory))

Comment: According to Wikipedia, [Linearity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity) of a function is given when $f(x)$ has the property 1. Additivity (also called the superposition property): $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$ and 2. Homogeneity of degree 1: $f(αx) = αf(x)$ for all $α.$ Both are not fulfilled, so it's not linear.

Comment: @draks: that's right. We agree that the function $H(X)$ doesn't satisfy this property. But my question is if someone has ever measured uncertainty with a different function (a linear one, for instance). Why should uncertainty be described by a non-linear function? Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Now I see and can say: I don't know. What do you need it for? *(Satisfying your curiosity is a valid answer)*

Comment: My research is about search engines. Given a query, I have a set of semantic categories and, for each category, the probability that the query belongs to this category. So I measure the ambiguity to classify the query in a category by evaluating the Shannon's entropy of its distribution of probabilities. But empirically I have observed this non-linearity and, yes, then I felt very curious.

Comment: Do you mind spelling your notation out a bit? Is $[a,b]$ a uniform distribution on that interval? If so, what generalization of the Shannon entropy are you using to continuous variables?

Comment: $distrib(q) = [a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_n]$ is a probability distribution. In this particular case, imagine that you have $n$ categories. Then $a_i$ is the probability for a given query $q$ to belong to the $i$-th category.

Precisely, what I do to measure the uncertainity for that query is: $-\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \,\log_n{a_i}$ (observe that the base of the logarithm is $n$, the number of categories). Why do you suggest that I should use a generalization for continuous variables?

Comment: @Kits89: If $a=(a_1, \dots, a_n), b=(b_1, \dots, b_n)$ are two PMFs, do you want your entropy measure to have $H(a+b)=H(a)+H(b)$?

Comment: @Ashok: Well not the _entropy measure_ but the _uncertainty measure_. Right, that could be a option..

Comment: Can you explain why you want an uncertainty measure with linearity? Usually people would want rather _additivity_, i.e., $H(a\star b)=H(a)+H(b)$ where $a\star b= (a_ib_j:i=1,\dots,n, j=1\dots, n)$, which apart from Shannon entropy, Renyi entropies have.

Comment: Well, I'm not asking for linearity, I'm looking for alternatives to Shannon's entropy. Why? Because I wonder: if the classification of a query uses a method like taking the category that has _maximum likelihood_, why the difference of uncertainty between $[0.9, 0.1]$ and $[0.99, 0.01]$ is much greater than $[0.6, 0.4]$ and $[0.61,0.39]$? It shouldn't grow at the same speed? I'll take a look to Renyi entropy..

Comment: @Ashok: The thing is that uncertainty of $[0.5,0,0,0,0,0.5]$ should be grater than $[0.1,0.2,0.1, 0.1,0.1, 0.4]$ because using the method that I said in my previous comment, in the first case we can't decide the category and in the second one, the category is 6th.

Comment: I think you want to measure a different aspect. For you, [0.4,0.4,0.2,0] should have lesser uncertainty than [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1], right? i.e., no. of maximal entries matters, right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4365/discussion-between-ashok-and-kits89)

Answer (score 3):

A linear function would not have some essential properties reasonably required of such a measure of uncertainty. Consider, as in your examples, distributions $[p, 1-p]$, with $0 \le p \le 1$, on a two-point sample space, and let $h(p)$ be the measure of uncertainty embodied by such a distribution.  Among the basic requirements of such a measure are that both $h(0) < h(1/2)$ and $h(1) < h(1/2)$ -- because a probability $p$ equal to $0$ or $1$ corresponds to less uncertainty than does any other value of $p$ -- but this is impossible if $h(p)$ is linear in $p$, or indeed if $h(p)$ is monotonic in $p$. [Standard axiomatic developments](http://www.mtm.ufsc.br/~taneja/book/node5.html) lead to the concave function $h(p) = - p \log p - (1-p) \log (1-p)$.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It was my mistake, I didn't mean linearity in the whole space but in $[0, \frac{1}{2}]$ and $[\frac{1}{2}, 1]$, in a way that also verifies the property that you just stated. (So, in the first interval it will monotonically increasing and in the second one, monotonically decreasing).

Comment: So, you could imagine the graph of the function that I propose similar to $-|x|$.